# Broadcom 4360 Wifi (2013 MacBook Air) on Juno?

Tags: wifi, drivers

Just installed Juno on a 2013 MacBook Air.

It's got a Broadcom 4360 wireless chip, which works great on the Live CD/USB, but the driver isn't there after install.

Is there a simple way to get wireless working on this device without having internet access?

Answer (score 1):

When you boot from the install media, wifi works.
So you could also reboot on the install media (cdrom, usb-key, or usb-hdd..)
chroot into your installed system and then `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`. After that you can reboot, unplug install media, `bcmwl-kernel-source` will still be installed on your system, wifi will work normally.

To chroot, boot from the install media, open a terminal, mount your installed system on `/media/target`

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/target && sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/target
$ sudo mount ‐‐bind /dev /media/target/dev
$ sudo mount ‐‐bind /proc /media/target/proc
$ sudo mount ‐‐bind /sys /media/target/sys
$ sudo chroot /media/target
$ sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Answer (score 1):

connect via ethernet and run update, the driver is included in it:

bcmwl-kernel-source
    Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source
    Version: 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.3

Answer (score 0):

You need to install bcmwl-kernel-source package somehow.
Possible solutions are..

1. If you have smartphone, share its connection via Bluetooth or USB, and install bcmwl-kernel-source package from AppCenter or `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`.
2. Temporarily copy cdrom line on /etc/apt/sources.list in Live environment to your installed environment and `sudo apt update  && sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`